# Accessing static member variable using boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I'm trying to port a working *C++* code from *Windows/Visual C++ 2010* to *Linux (Ubuntu 12.04)* platform<sup>1</sup>.

> The code is trying to access a static member variable using boost's `shared_ptr`. When I port this code to Linux, I get: `"undefined reference to Test::TYPE"`, even though it compiles and works fine on Windows.

Here is the test program which demonstrate the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(int x, int y) : a_(x), b_(y) { }

    void print() { std::cout << "a_ : " << a_ << ", b_ : " << b_ <<   std::endl; }

    static const unsigned int TYPE = 5;

private:
    int a_;
    int b_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Test> pTest(new Test(10, 20));
    pTest->print();
    std::cout << "Test Type is: " << pTest->TYPE << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know why GCC gives undefined reference for above code?

Note: It works fine If I use a simple pointer instead of boost `shared_ptr` .

---

<sup>1. I'm using Ubuntu Linux 12.04, gcc version 4.6.4 and boost 1.44.</sup>

Comment: Can not reproduce on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: works perfectly on Ubuntu gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04) with  Boost version: 1.46.1

Answer (score 0):

"undefined reference" is a linker error. Apparently, the compiler uses the address of the constant, possibly because it is not smart enough to realize that it is always the same constant.

When used in a way that requires the address of a constant, like passing it by reference, you have to also provide a definition of the constant (in some .cpp file).

Accessing a constant through a shared pointer seems a bit more complicated than necessary. Using `Test::TYPE` would make it easier for the compiler.